# In c# xml comments, how to refer to other method's specific augument?

Tags: c#, xml, comments

For instance, I have one method first:

```
int GetNumber(out double solvingTimeInSeconds);
```

Then I call another method:

```
void PrintSolvingTime(double _solvingTimeInSeconds);
```

When I do documentation on `<param name="solvingTimeInSeconds">` I just want to use the documentation from augument `solvingTimeInSeconds` in method `GetNumber`, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, as far as I'm aware. They're separate methods - there's no guarantee that the value passed into `PrintSolvingTime` will have come from `solvingTimeInSeconds`.

Of course, if you created a new type (`SolvingResult`) which encapsulated the solution and the time taken, you could make `PrintSolvingTime` an instance method on `SolvingResult`, and that could refer to the `SolvingTime` property...

Comment: well if it is as designed I will not try to break it. Thanks.